# focus is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Focus method is not working in Firefox only l basic steps to overwrite function in Firefox. kindly provide solution html code and Js code is added below . thanks in advance. Using fiddle link you can access and provide workaround as soon as possible.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id$='.errors']:first").css("background-color", "#FFFFCC");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("[id$='.errors']:first").attr("tabindex", -1).focus();
    alert(document.activeElement.innerHTML + " is focussed");
  }, 300);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="userid.errors" class="lp">User id is missing</div>
<div id="age.errors" class="lp">age is missing</div>
```

**Fiddle link** is : http://jsfiddle.net/x7euD/3/

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me in Firefox - although I'm not sure exactly what you expect focussing on a `div` element to do?

Comment: yeah, please specify what you mean with "is not working"...

Comment: Which version of firefox are you working on

Comment: firefox version is  54

Comment: Hi Yo Yo , Firefox version is 54.0.1 (32-bit)

Comment: Hi  Rory McCrossan , focus means one blue border will come right that is not happening in firefox

Comment: Can also confirm that this is not working in firefox 57; works in chrome though

Comment: I also have this same problem. focus in firefox means dotted line around border, in chrome blue line around the border

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code. It is working on firefox and chrome both browser.

```
  <div id="userid.errors" class="lp">User id is missing</div>
  <div id="age.errors" class="lp">age is missing</div>

  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("[id$='.errors']:first").css("background-color","#FFFFCC");
      setTimeout(function(){
         $("[id$='.errors']:first").attr("tabindex",-1).focus();
         alert(document.activeElement.innerHTML+ " is focussed");
      },300);
    });
```

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer

Comment: Yes, but I can't comment directly without reputation 50 so just told him that It is working

Comment: firefox version is 54.0.1 (32-bit)

Comment: can you please check "trigger"

$("[id$='.errors']:first").attr("tabindex",-1).trigger('focus');

Answer (score 0):

ok, so since the alert box shows us the correct item, it *is* working in firefox, i guess you're missing the blue border?

if i click on the focused div after running the snippet it shows a small dotted border. I'm not quite sure, but i think the browsers visualice a focused item differently (? - anyone correct me on this if i'm wrong, please)

What you could do is to add an extra border to your element, if you're bothered about it:

```js
   

         $(document).ready(function() {
            
     $("[id$='.errors']:first").attr("tabindex",-1).focus();

// HERE WE SEE THAT SETTING THE FOCUS WORKED:

      $(document.activeElement).css("border", "solid green");

             });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="userid.errors" class="lp">User id is missing</div>
<div id="age.errors" class="lp">age is missing</div>
```

Comment: That dotted line should come without clicking. Nothing seems to work for me.